# Do indirect objects in pdf always have an EOL marker after the obj keyword?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, binaryfiles

The [spec](https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/pdfstandards/pdfreference1.5_v6.pdf) section 3.2.9 says:

> The definition of an indirect object in a PDF file consists of its object number and
> generation number, followed by the value of the object itself bracketed between
> the keywords obj and endobj.

And then gives an example

```
12 0 obj
  (Brillig)
endobj
```

But it does not seem to mention if an EOL after the keyword `obj` is required. On the other hand, the spec emphasizes the necessity of EOL in case of `stream` keyword in section 3.2.7.

In practice, however, all pdf files I have examined seem to have an EOL after the `obj` keyword. Did I miss anything from the spec?

Comment: Actually you only refer to an old PDF reference. You had better work with a current pdf specification ISO 32000. (The pdf references were not considered normative in nature.) There you can read that even object number and generation number are separated by *white space*, not necessarily a single space character. So already between then might be a line break. 

Comment: @mkl Thanks for pointing out the new spec. But ISO 32000 still does not mention whitespace **AFTER** the `obj` keyword.

Comment: Right, my comment was more a side remark, not an answer to your actual question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you had better use the actual PDF specification, i.e. ISO 32000, not one of the old PDF References which were not considered normative in nature.

That been said, even the actual spec does not require an EOL after the **obj** keyword, so

```
12 0 obj (A string in an indirect object) endobj
```

is valid.

Actually the spec points out that white-space is used to separate the numbers. Thus, even constructs like this

```
12   % A comment 
0

     obj (A string in an indirect object) endobj
```

are valid.

If you look at specific profiles of PDF, though, the situation can differ.

PDF/A-1 (ISO 19005-1) for example requires:

> The object number and generation number shall be separated by a single white-space character. The generation number and **obj** keyword shall be separated by a single white-space character.
>
> The object number and **endobj** keyword shall each be preceded by an EOL marker. The **obj** and **endobj** keywords shall each be followed by an EOL marker.

Comment: I didn't even know the existence of various pdf profiles and such

Comment: Those extra profiles are meant for special purposes. E.g. PDF/A profiles are for archiving, PDF/X profiles for professional printing, PDF/UA for universal accessibility,...